# Show and play uploaded videos in all formats in Media Gallery Module in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-modules

Need to have a feature that enables to show the uploaded video formats just like youtube embedded videos are shown in the media gallery module - http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery.

How can this be achieved? Please advise.

Thanks,

Greg